# What is the difference between arriving at the 'avoided crossing' point of a two-level system adiabatically and non-adiabatically?

Tags: adiabatic, two-level-system

In the simplest case of the 'avoided crossing phenomenon' we can assume a two level system that its eigenstates $E_1(n)$ and $E_2(n)$ are functions of some continuous variable n, and there is some coupling (disturbance) between the two. If it happens to be that for some value of this variable, the two bare states have the same energy, then at this point the eigenstates will hybridize to form new eigenstates, and an avoided crossing gap will be formed. Now let's assume we prepare our two-level-system in the low energy ground state corresponding to $E_1$ and start tuning the parameter n to bring the system to the avoided crossing point, wait for a while (maybe a time of ~ $1/\Delta$, where $\Delta$ is the gap), and then tune n back into its initial value. Let's assume we do it once adiabatically and once non-adiabatically. What will be the difference? can you show calculation?

Comment: Quick hint : Landau-Zener formula.

Comment: That's a good start, but still I am not sure what will happen if we wait at the avoided crossing point. I guess that in the non adiabatic case we will have os illations between the bare states (assuming no energy relaxation), while in the adiabatic case the two level system will stay in the lower hybredized state. Is it correct?